# Ionic framework- Screen flickering in Android when entering the inputs

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

HTML part

```
<ion-view  cache-view="false" view-title="" hide-nav-bar="true">
<ion-content class="padding input-center" style="background: url(img/background.jpg) center; background-size: cover;" ng-show="viewEntered">
<div class="row responsive-sm padding remvoeBP">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="app-logo"><img src="img/logo.png"></div> 

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <label class="item item-input" ng-hide="showCity" style="background-color:transparent; border:none; border-bottom:1px solid white;">
              <i class="icon ion-location placeholder-icon" style="color:black;"></i>
              <input type="text" placeholder="City" ng-change="searchCity(city_suggestion)" ng-model="city_suggestion">
            </label>

            <label class="item item-input" ng-show="showCity" style="background-color:transparent; border:none; border-bottom:1px solid white;">
              <i class="icon ion-location placeholder-icon" style="color:black;"></i>
              <input type="text" ng-click="changeCity()" ng-model="cityName">
            </label>

            <div ng-show="cityList" class="list">
              <li class="item" ng-click="selectedCity(city.city_id, city.name)" ng-repeat="city in searchCityList" >{{city.name}}</li>
              <input type="hidden" name="cityId" ng-value="cityId"/>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col" >
            <label class="item item-input" ng-hide="showArea" style="background-color:transparent; border:none; border-bottom:1px solid white;">     
              <i class="icon ion-android-navigate placeholder-icon" style="color:black;"></i>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Area" ng-change="searchArea(area_suggestion)" ng-model="area_suggestion">
            </label>

           <label class="item item-input" ng-show="showArea" style="background-color:transparent; border:none; border-bottom:1px solid white;">
              <i class="icon ion-android-navigate placeholder-icon" style="color:black;"></i>
             <input type="text" ng-click="changeArea()" ng-model="areaName">
           </label>

           <div ng-show="areaList" class="list">
             <li class="item" ng-click="selectedArea(area.area_id, area.name)" ng-repeat="area in searchAreaList">{{area.name}}</li>
           </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <button class="button icon-left ion-android-search login-button-center" style="background-color:#AD1114;" ng-click="searchRestaurant(cityId,areaId)">
          Search
        </button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My controller code

```
angular.module('starter.locationControllers', [])

.controller('LocationCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http, $ionicPopup, baseUrl, $ionicLoading) {

  $scope.$on("$ionicView.enter", function () { 
    $scope.viewEntered = true; 
  });
  $scope.$on("$ionicView.beforeLeave", function () { 
    $scope.viewEntered = false; 
  });

  $ionicLoading.show({
    template:'<div class="loader"><svg class="circular"><circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></svg></div>'
  });

  $http({
method : "POST",
url : baseUrl+"user_id="+localStorage.getItem('user_id')+"&methodName=cart.clear"
   }).then(function mySucces(response) {

$ionicLoading.hide();

$scope.cityList = false;
$scope.showCity = false;
$scope.city_suggestion = '';
$scope.cityId = '';
$scope.areaId = '';

$scope.searchCity = function(city_suggestion) {
  $ionicLoading.show({
    template:'<div class="loader"><svg class="circular"><circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></svg></div>'
  });

  $http.get(baseUrl+'methodName=city.suggestion&query='+city_suggestion, { cache: true}).then(function(response) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    $scope.cityList = true;
    $scope.searchCityList = response.data.responseMsg;
  });
};  

$scope.selectedCity = function(cityId, cityName) {
  $scope.showCity = true;
  $scope.cityList = false;
  $scope.cityName = cityName;
  $scope.cityId = cityId;
}

$scope.changeCity = function() {
  $scope.city_suggestion = {};
  $scope.cityName = {};
  $scope.showCity = false;
}

$scope.areaList = false;
$scope.showArea = false;
$scope.area_suggestion = '';

$scope.searchArea = function(area_suggestion) {

  $ionicLoading.show({
    template:'<div class="loader"><svg class="circular"><circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></svg></div>'
  }); 

  $http.get(baseUrl+'methodName=area.suggestion&city_id='+$scope.cityId+'&query='+area_suggestion, { cache: true}).then(function(response) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    $scope.areaList = true;
    $scope.searchAreaList = response.data.responseMsg;
  });
};  

$scope.selectedArea = function(areaId, areaName) {
  $scope.showArea = true;
  $scope.areaList = false;
  $scope.areaName = areaName;
  $scope.areaId = areaId;
}

$scope.changeArea = function() {
  $scope.area_suggestion = {};
  $scope.areaName = {};
  $scope.showArea = false;
} 

$scope.searchRestaurant = function(cityId, areaId) {

  if(cityId == '') {
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'Dear User',
      template: 'Please select city.'
    });

    return false;
  }

  if(areaId == '') {
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
    title: 'Dear User',
      template: 'Please select area.'
    });

    return false;
  }

  window.localStorage.removeItem("cityId");
  window.localStorage.removeItem("areaId");

  localStorage.setItem('cityId', cityId);
  localStorage.setItem('areaId', areaId);

  $state.go('restaurantList', {cityId: cityId, areaId:areaId});
}

});

});
```

System information

Your system information:

```
 ordova CLI: 6.4.0
 Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.13
 Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
 ios-deploy version: Not installed
 ios-sim version: Not installed
 OS: Windows 10
 Node Version: v7.2.0
 Xcode version: Not installed
```

My app screen flickers when giving input. I refer some links, but still i'm suffering from this problem. More detail please click https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGOrjMK6gmM&feature=youtu.be here.

Answer (score 0):

Input elements must be inside **form** tag like

```
<form id="calcForm" name="calcForm">
    ...... Input fields......
</form>
```

Also dont-leave **view-title** blank in ion-view.

Comment: In ion-view use like this   <ion-view view-title="" cache-view="false">     Content  </ion-view>.  Sometime caches may cause problem

Answer (score 0):

Add these two properties to prevent flickering effects:

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;   
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Apply also to flickering elements which AREN'T being animated for the same fix.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where i need to add these code.

Comment: add this code at flickering element's parent node. some time you may need to add it in child node also.

Answer (score 0):

A flickering screen could be due to authentication checking issue. For example, when you are logged out but your code still checks whether your data exists in the storage which in fact may exist.

On Chrome browser, I suggest that you go to **More Tools -> Developer Tools -> Application.** Then select your ionic storage and clear database.

Answer (score -1):

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{
    scrollPadding: false,
    scrollAssist: true,
    autoFocusAssist: false
  })
],
```

File: `app.modules.ts`